# Why doesn't malloced string not work with strcat?

Tags: malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, strcat

In the following code, on commenting strcat, str1 is returned as initially declared till word "Enjoy" but on using strcat, it throws segfault. I am confused why concatenation is not taking place since I declared a dynamic allocated string.

```
char * kitchen(int cost)
    {
        cost = 100;
        char *str1 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)* 70);
        str1 = "\n Food's ready bruh, Enjoyy!!";
        char *str2 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)* 70);
        sprintf(str2, " But do pay %d", cost );
        strcat(str1, str2);
        return str1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
str1 = "\n Food's ready bruh, Enjoyy!!";
```

With

```
strcpy(str1, "\n Food's ready bruh, Enjoyy!!");
```

[Live demo here.](https://repl.it/@robertwharvey/StormyDistantInformationtechnology)

Despite your dynamic allocation, `"\n Food's ready bruh, Enjoyy!!"` is still a string literal, and is still treated by C as read-only.  Your assignment merely points `str1` to that string literal.